# How can I change .css class property - background: url('') for each item javascript / typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, typescript

This is how I display products from database:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products;">
  <div id="article1" class="article">
    <p class="product-price">{{product.mpc | number}}</p>
    <p class="product-title">{{product.title}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there is .css class "article" on  with id="article1"..

And here is the `.css` article class:

```
.article {
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('../../src/assets/images/funny-photo.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center, center;
}
```

As it is possible to see background: url of this class .article is hardcoded:

`background: url('../../src/assets/images/funny-photo.jpg');`

How can I for each item set different `background: url` with corresponding url from database?

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: Off the top of my head, you can make your `background-image` an inline style added to your image div inside your `ngFor` loop. You can then set that value to whatever based on your dataset.

Comment: Have you tried like.
// style.backgroundImage
[style.backgroundImage]="'url('+ product.imageUrl +')'"

Comment: Just an advice not related to the question. Avoid using same id for multiple divs (since it is inside `ngFor`). It can save a lot of `it's behaving crazy` bugs in the end.

Comment: @nightgaunt Good advice! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `[style.background]` and set in url the `url` from current product**

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products;">
  <div id="article1" class="article" [style.background]="'url('+product.image+')'">
    <p class="product-price">{{product.mpc | number}}</p>
    <p class="product-title">{{product.title}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if its angular then try

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + photoURL + ')'}"></div>
```

Inside your ngFor loop